# VIM NERDtree * behind filenames

Tags: git, vim, nerdtree

All files in NERDtree have a `*` behind the name. This is true for all files, regardless of folder, file type or if `.git` is present in the directory. The `*`'s just appeared all of a sudden, they have not been visible before.

[image: Image of the problem]

How do i get rid of the `*`'s behind the filenames?

I am using the [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) Vim Distribution together with MacVim 7.4.

Comment: Can it be, that the files are marked as executable? (I.e., `ls -l` in those folders shows `-rwxrwx---` or similar with an `x` somewhere.)

Comment: Yes that was the problem, thank you! I had ran a yeoman generator in the wrong folder by accident that changed file permissions for all the files.

Comment: Yeoman, Janus, Git, Vim, the command-line… you are going too fast.